# Spotify web player "Playback of protected content is not enabled"

Tags: streaming, media

Opening Spotify Web player brings up DRM page:

[image: DRM]

This happened first with my RasPi 4<sup>1</sup> default Chromium<sup>2</sup>. "Spotify Support" -button brings up [web player help](https://support.spotify.com/us/article/web-player-help/) which advises

> 1. In your browser address bar, enter chrome://settings/content
> 2. Under Protected content, switch on Allow site to play protected content.

Item specified in 2. doesn't exist, but "Protected content IDs" does, and is set to "Sites can play protected content".

Long story short:

- I `apt` installed Brave Browser Version 1.50.114 Chromium: 112.0.5615.49 (Official Build) (64-bit) - same result
- I `apt` installed Firefox 102.9.0esr (64-bit) - same result. Spotify Support page gives equally incorrect instructions. Mozilla's [Watch DRM content on Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-drm) mentions "Play DRM-controlled content" checkmark under *Settings -> General* - the checkmark doesn't exist.

Mozilla support page brought up [Widevine](https://developers.google.com/widevine/drm/overview). Contrary to the support page it's neither installed with FFox, nor available as an extension. Can't find it for Chromium either.

Further research brought up libwidevinecdm0, which is available in repos (v. 4.10.2252.0+1). I `apt` installed it, cleared all data from both FFox and Brave and tried again. No help, I can't get past that DRM page.

As this is about the web player, I might have posted this to Web Applications. However this works perfectly fine on my daily driver (Debian 11 / Brave Version 1.49.132 Chromium: 111.0.5563.147 / Firefox 102.9.0esr - same settings) so to me this seems purely a RasPi OS issue.

What next?

---

<sup>1</sup>OS info; updated today 11:00 EET:

```
pg@MediaRasPi:~ $ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: MediaRasPi
         Icon name: computer
        Machine ID: 5a85acbf0ac045c9a053c59bc7667daa
           Boot ID: 2d3c6896e23e4b8181bee3bad682c971
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
            Kernel: Linux 6.1.21-v8+
      Architecture: arm64
```

<sup>2</sup>Version 109.0.5414.112 (Official Build) Built on Debian , running on Debian 11 (64-bit)